# passing authentication information to cadence activities

Tags: cadence-workflow

I am trying to use cadence to orchestrate several micro service api calls on behalf of the user. Each api call needs to be authenticated with a short lived JWT to identify the user. I expect I will need to implement a token refreshing capability but I still need to propagate the user's identity to all activities. What is the recommended way to do so? Are ContextPropagators appropriate? Should I just stick with plain old inputs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ContextPropagators were designed specifically for purposes like security and distributed testing. So they are absolutely appropriate for your use case.